# Отсутствие плавности между ключевыми кадрами анимации

Tags: анимация, three.js

Есть данная проблема. Анимация сделана в Блокбенч, и пересена в three.js посредством экспорта gltf. Начнём с того что анимация в целом не воспроизводится самостоятельно, и только при переборе циклом начинает работать без плавности между ключевыми кадрами. (В блокбенч указан тип интерполяции Smooth)

```
loader.load("/assets/models/doll", gltf => {
    let doll = gltf;

    let mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( doll.scene );
    let action = mixer.clipAction( doll.animations[0] );
    action.play();
    mixer.update( new THREE.Clock().getDelta() ) // Пробовал также просто 1, вместо дельты
    
    setInterval(()=>{
        action.play();
        // mixer.update(1) // Так же пробовал обновить миксер
    }, 2000);
});
```